# Change Excel day name to other languages

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I modify Excel List to get day names returned by TEXT(TODAY()) e.g. in other languages instead of English ?

Answer (score 22):

You would have to put in the LanguageID into the format string:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324097

Here you go:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"[$-407]DDDD")
```

this should result in

```
Donnerstag, Freitag, etc ...
```

And because I am alway unsure about english formulars, here is my original for german users:

```
=TEXT(HEUTE());"[$-409]TTTT")
```

this results in the current day in english instead of german language

Comment: Wow, works great. I didn't know it's possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I changed below day names to my language and it works

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(B4),"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")
```

Source https://exceljet.net/formula/get-day-name-from-date

Comment: Nice Answer, could even go further with `=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A3),"[$-419]ddd")
```

List of language IDs: [here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html)

Nice formatting guide: [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/821-excel-convert-date-to-weekday-month-name.html)