# Excel: Using the TEXT function for spreadsheets used by users with different regional settings

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am using the TEXT function like `=TEXT(B1, "ddd")` where `B1` is formated as date to display the weekday. This works fine on an english regional system.

On a machine with a german regional setting the formula doesn't work because the format literal must be "ttt". So on a german system the formula would have to be `=TEXT(B1, "ttt")`

How can that same spreadsheet be used on a system with an English regional setting and on another machine with a German regional setting?

Comment: You might be better off using a `choose(weekday(` function

Comment: This will result in weekday names in one language, but it is far better than the original solution with the text function. I will use it. Thank you

Comment: Related: [Change Excel day name to other languages](http://superuser.com/q/477385/354511) and [Excel TEXT function does not work properly](http://superuser.com/q/730012/354511).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't let you use the value in later calculations, but it's a reasonable work-around for the problem you face -

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(B1),"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
```